# SSRS - How to use a dynamic date on all tablix table

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that contains 9 different data set (see below). For each dataset I have a date dynamic date range parameter that is pulling data year to date. Is there a way to define the dynamic year to date once and call that variable for each data set?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the values in as parameters for each dataset if the query needs to have them. There isn't a decent way to pass date ranges as a single entity, so pass in a datetime for each end of the range.

You can create two hidden parameters or variables at the report level. I would create the hidden parameters with default values. This will let you debug things easily as well, and may be useful for subscriptions.